# Referencing a .php file within html without changing extension?

Tags: php, html, web

I have a text box which has autocomplete (Similar to Google) when the user types in it. I have a .php file called "getautocomplete.php" how do I reference this within my index.html?

THank you

Comment: You need to call it through ajax. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/ A tutorial on the topic as well, http://markonphp.com/autocomplete-php-jquery-mysql-part1/.

Comment: What do you mean by reference it?

Comment: When someone starts typing in the text area, it will include my file called "getautocomplete.php" as this looks up in the database the applicable text to display as autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript ajax example with typed data to send to php script:

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
var typedtxt = document.getElementById("textbox").value;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert(responseText);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getautocomplete.php?typedtxt="+typedtxt,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#call through ajax
#ajax syntax to call
$.post("getautocomplete.php",function(data){

#hence data will have response returned from getautocomplete.php

alert(data);
})
```